# Export Web Map Task: Configure HTTP response headers

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing, export, printing, server-object-extension

Is there any way to configure the http headers (response headers) of a geoprossessing task hosted by ArcGIS for Server?

I would like to make the [export web map task](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ExportWebMap_specification/0154000004w8000000/), return an image which would be directly downloaded by my browser.

Comment: Do you believe that I could tweak the Exprort/Print task using server object extensions at ArcGIS  and add a content -disposition response header like [here] ?(http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/concepts/engine/index.html#/What_s_new_in_Server_Object_Extensions_at_ArcGIS_Server_10_1/00010000075m000000/)